# Any way to tell what part of a WPF Ellipse shape a user has clicked on?

Tags: wpf, ellipse

This may seem like a silly question, but is there some way to determine what part (say, a quadrant) of an Ellipse that a user clicked on?

Or is the only option to just figure it out based on mouse point coordinates relative to the shape itself?

I'm working on a control that allows the user to click on any part of the ellipse and drag it to resize if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out the mouse coordinates in relationship to the shape should be fairly easy. Check the X coordinate and see if it is greater than or equal to `Shape.Width / 2`. Then do the same with Y and Shape.Height. It should give you the correct quadrant the mouse was clicked in.

Comment: Of course I ask the question and wind up thinking about it some more and that's the direction I'm heading in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) that the general equation for an ellipse is:

[image: equation for ellipse].

The points within the ellipse are the ones for which the equation yields `<= 1`.

If the ellipse is circumscribed to a rectangle `R`, then:

- `(x0,y0) = center(R)`
- `a = width(R)/2`
- `b = height(R)/2`
- `(x,y)` is the clicked point.